# How to invoke C# function from Lua script?

Tags: c#, lua

I will write some test cases in .lua file and execute them automatically sometimes without rebuild .exe.

Is there any way to call C# function from lua file.

Note : C# functions have some struct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Lua is coded in C, and hence can only work with C and C++ using the C-Lua API.
However, for C#, you'll need to find an external API to work with Lua, sadly.